# delete function in ajax doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to use Ajax to delete a row from mysql without refreshing ,but script doesn't work.

```
// ============ delete.php ===========
if(isset($_GET['delete_id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['delete_id'];
    $dquery = "SELECT url FROM test1 WHERE id='$id'";

    foreach($db->query($dquery) as $deleterow){
        deleteDirectory("test1/" . $deleterow['url']);
    }

    $result = $db->query("DELETE FROM test1 WHERE id ='$id'");
}

// ============ manage.php ===============
    while($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      $id1 = $row["id"];
       echo '
        <tr>

            <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['subscribers'].'</td>
            <td><a href="#"></a></td>
      <td><input type="submit" class="delete" id="'.$id1.'" value="Delete"></td>
        </tr>
        ';
    }

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".delete").click(function(){
   var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
   $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'delete.php',
      data:'delete_id='+del_id,
      success:function(data) {
        if(data) {   alert(del_id);
          $("body").load("manage.php");
        } else { alert("Error"); }
      }
   });
 });
});
 </script>
```

I also tried to include manage.php into delete.php and use $id1 , and worked, but they delete another id

Comment: Could you print out the $id in the delete.php? Try that

Comment: through the first method does not work, but in the second method dysplaing last id

Answer (score 0):

In the file "delete.php", you must substitute SELECT by DELETE, because the function is DELETE. Then, the code should be something like that:

```
$dquery = "DELETE FROM test1 WHERE id='$id'"; (...)
```

And the function is called only one time how showed above.

Comment: I think the problem is the id because deletes the last

Comment: In ajax, your method is POST and in the file "delete.php", the method is GET. Then, this can be one of the errors!!

Comment: the same problem :(

Comment: Do you refer to this part ? 
success:function(data) {
        if(data) {   alert(del_id);
          $("body").load("manage.php");
        } else { alert("Error"); }
  } 

del_id shows true id of the element

Comment: In ajax insert only this to see what happens: success: "function(data){alert(data)}"